# Как получить данные из массива

Tags: массивы, php

Как получить данные из этого массива:

```
stdClass Object ( [data] => Array ( [0] => cas@ [1] => adx [2] => ved [3] => fsr [4] => fff [5] => dff [6] => cas ) )
```

Comment: А чем сам массив вам не данные?

Расскажите, чего именно вы хотите добиться.

Comment: Нужно получить например cas@ Пробовал так $data = $data[data][0] но пишет ошибку

Comment: @ReinRaus, Спасибо заработало

Comment: @as-live не забудьте принять ответ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Может потому что надо так:

```
$data->data[0]
```

Это же все таки объект, а не массив.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = json_decode($data, true);

echo $array['data'][0];
```